# What is the difference between these two ways of adding Neural Network layers in Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, theano

I'm using Keras with a Theano as a backend and I have Sequential neural network model.

I wonder is there a difference between following?

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
```

and

```
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are essentially the same. The advantage of putting it separately is that you can add other layers (say `BatchNormalization`) in between.

In Keras, if not specified, `Convolution2D` will use the 'linear' activation by default, which is just the identity function

```
def linear(x):
    '''
    The function returns the variable that is passed in, so all types work.
    '''
    return x
```

and all that `Activation` layer does is applying the activation function to the input

```
def call(self, x, mask=None):
    return self.activation(x)
```

Edit:

> So basically `Convolution2D(activation = 'relu')` applies relu activation function after performing convolution, which is the same as applying `Activation('relu')` after `Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)`

the last two lines of the `call` function of the `Convolution2D` layer are

```
output = self.activation(output)
return output
```

where `output` is the output of convolution. So we know applying the activation function is the last step of `Convolution2D`.

Source code:
`Convolution2D` layer: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/a981a8c42c316831183cac7598266d577a1ea96a/keras/layers/convolutional.py
`Activation` layer: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/a981a8c42c316831183cac7598266d577a1ea96a/keras/layers/core.py
activation functions: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py

Comment: Just to clarify. So basically Convolution2D(activation = 'relu') applies relu activation function after performing convolution, which is the same as applying Activation('relu') after Convolution2D(32, 3, 3)?

Comment: @angubenko yes, I added some code and explanation in the answer, hope that helps.